# Javascript InfoVis SpaceTree: Navigation (Drag tree and select node) issue

Tags: javascript, charts, visualization, infovis

I am using the Javascript InfoVis SpaceTree. And my SpaceTree have more then 500 nodes. Everything working fine until I drag the tree (navigate). It Depends on how far I drag it, Then select node which have next level tree, that selected node will rendered somewhere/outside the view port. So I have to drag the chart back so that it can be seen.

Is there a way to tell SpaceTree to center the next selected node to the view port before redrawing the nodes?

*Ref.*
https://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example1.html

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Welcome to SE. you should provide what you've done so far. which also help others to solve your issue. Also its good if you can provide fiddle for it.

Comment: Hello Shivam, Please refer this URL as an example. https://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example1.html then change tree orientation top, then click on any node and drag the view port, then click on any node, which does not get centered.

Comment: Please add this URL in your question detail so its handy to understand other visitors.